# How to check whether the value is present in mutiple tables

Tags: .net, database, oracle, c#-4.0, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am going to insert a few data from a machine generated text files in to a single table in oracle database.But these values can be present in multiple tables in same database which was updated earlier through different source.So i want to check whether the value is present and matching in those other tables.In order to do that i created a column named "`Ismatching`" in the new single table.But i don't know how to check whether the value is present or not.I am using ADO.NET to push data in to oracle database.Following is a query i used to fetch data from multiple tables `MN_SITE` ,`MN_CELL` and MN_PSITE and the new table i am going to insert table is `Mn_tabletest` where i created a new column "`Ismatching`" .Following is a query i used to fetch data from mutiple tables and the same column value i am going to insert in to the table `Mn_tabletest`.But i don't know how to update new column "`Ismatching`" in table `Mn_tabletest` while inserting ,can anybody guide me here

```
SELECT        MN_SITE.TECH_CODE, MN_SITE.VENDOR_CODE, MN_SITE.SITE_ID, MN_SITE.BSC_ID, MN_PSITE.GEO_ZONE_CODE, MN_PSITE.REGION_CODE, MN_CELL.TALIM, 
                         MN_CELL.BTS_NAME, MN_CELL.CELL_INFO, MN_CELL.CELL_INFO AS EXPR1, MN_CELL.CELL_NAME, MN_CELL.BSIC, MN_CELL.SECTOR_NAME, 
                         MN_CELL.HOPPING_MODE, MN_CELL.BSPWR, MN_CELL.DEFINED_TCH_FRQ, MN_CELL.TRX_NOS, MN_CELL.NO_OF_FREQ, MN_CELL.HSN, MN_CELL.LAC, 
                         MN_CELL.BCC, MN_CELL.NCC, MN_CELL.BAND, MN_CELL.CELL_SLNO, MN_CELL.CELL_ID
FROM            MN_CELL INNER JOIN
                         MN_SITE ON MN_CELL.SITE_SLNO = MN_SITE.SITE_SLNO INNER JOIN
                         MN_PSITE ON MN_SITE.PSITE_SLNO = MN_PSITE.PSITE_SLNO
WHERE        (MN_CELL.CELL_SLNO = '128691')
```

**UPDATE**

i am not doing insert and update both.I am inserting rows in to a table, but one of the column "Ismatching" is based on the current inserting rows are present in other multiple tables

Comment: Look at the MERGE statement.

Comment: @OldProgrammer can you give a simple protoype.i am not doing insert and update both.I am inserting rows in to a table, but one of the column "Ismatching" is based on the current inserting rows are present in other multiple tables

Comment: If you want to insert from a select that a field should read data from another table, Use an inner-select for that field ;).

Comment: @shA.t i dont know how to do that,can you give me the code

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by oldProgrammer you can use MERGE statement to insert your data into your actual table rather than first inserting data into "Ismatching" column.

SYNTAX for Merge:
    `MERGE INTO actual_table A
    USING (SELECT B_columns FROM reference_table B) 
    ON (A.column1 = B.column1)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET B.column2=....
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (A.column1, A.column2,....)
    VALUES (A.column1, A.column2,....);`

Here your column1 will be a primary column which will used to check if data exists.

For more details on merge please check: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: can you write the query based on the query i posted.i mean based on the table MN_SITE,MN_CELL and MN_PSITE